# Run bash script even after closing terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal, shell

I have basic script

```
while sleep 120; do cmd; done &
```

which i want to run even after I close the terminal. How can i achieve that?

I tried

```
nohup while sleep 120; do cmd; done &

disown while sleep 120; do cmd; done &
```

but i recieve

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

both the times. Thanks
ps: I am new to terminal.

Comment: that's not a script, and it doesn't make sense. You can't use sleep 120 as a while condition. Also, what does `done` do? It's not a command that I'm familiar with, nor is `disown`.

Comment: @HerbWolfe I use it to run some terminal command after every 120 sec. But when i close the terminal it stops executing

Comment: That isn't a script. You're just stringing some commands together, with the wrong syntax.

Comment: then how can i fix this command to run every two sec even after I close terminal. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's because `while` is a shell builtin. This should work:

```
nohup bash -c "while sleep 120; do some_commands; done" &`
```